# Where does imageConfig (HUGO) look for images when building the site?

Tags: hugo, blogdown

I'm trying to get the size (width and height) of an image located inside my static folder

I wrote:

```
{{$imagelink := print "/static" (.Params.image | relURL) }}
{{$imgData := imageConfig $imagelink }}
<p>{{ $imgData.Height }}</p>
<p>{{ $imgData.Width }}</p>
```

where `.Params.image` is taken from the YAML metadata, e.g.: `image: "images/my-image.PNG"` of each post.

The previous works well if I save the file when the server is running. I can get the width and the height, but if I build my site with `build_site(local = TRUE)` (I'm using `blogdown`) HUGO can't find the images.

I tried debugging the error with `{{ errorf "Specified file at %s not found." $imagelink }}`, but whatever path I try it never founds the images.

I also followed [this tutorial about imageConfig](https://kodify.net/hugo/functions/imageconfig-function/), where they point out the following:

[image]

but `{{$imagelink := print "/static/static" (.Params.image | relURL) }}` doesn't work either.

I haven't found official documentation regarding this issue. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: As the first step to debug this problem, I suggest you print out the value of `$imagelink` before applying the `imageConfig` function.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Yihui. The value of `$imagelink` is what I expect: `"/static/images/my-image.PNG"`. The funny thing is that If serve the site and then I call the partial where the code is I can get the dimensions of the image. But if I build the site I get `<imageConfig $imagelink>: error calling imageConfig: image: unknown format` I thought it could be the `.PNG` extension but the same problem arises with `.png`, so I'm not sure where HUGO is looking for the image when I build the site. `static/static` doesn't work either. (My images are in the static folder of the root)

Answer (score 0):

This issue was solved upgrading HUGO and blogdown to the latest version